# Transformar int em byte em python

Tags: python, int, byte

Olá,
Preciso transformar um valor int para byte.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

angulo = 90

ser.write(angulo)

#while 1 :
print ser.readline()
```

Preciso mandar um valor para o Arduino, a princípio, só aceita em byte.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Só usar:

```
valor = bytes([90])
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq).

---

Para converter de byte para inteiro, use:

```
int.from_bytes(meus_bytes, byteorder='big')
```

Se for *big endian*, e

```
int.from_bytes(neus_bytes, byteorder='little')
```

se for *little endian*.

Comment: Obrigado! cara, preciso, agora no arduino, fazer ao contrário, receber esse valor em bytes e transformar em int. Como fazer?

Comment: Veja minha edição.

Comment: valor[0]   - em Python 3 quando você recuperar valores de um objeto bytes usando índidices, você os vê como números inteiros (sem sinal).